# WP_Query search by multiple meta key and distance

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I am having two meta keys, longitude and latitude, and what I am trying to do is the equivalent of the google store location algorithm for distance, in wp_query:

> SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) *
>   cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(
>   radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25
>   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

What I am trying to do, is get a list of custom post types (stores) that contain long/lat (custom fields), and having an x distance (it's for a store locator, like google's example).

I have already done it with $wpdb way, but I am looking for a wp_query because I want the paging and the extra filtering by using/removing an add_filter() directive to the page. Is it possible to execute such complex query, or should I stick to $wpdb method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that. There are filters available in WP_Query that enable you to modify the query just as you like. The filter `posts_clauses` filters all of the parts of the query together. There are also filters specific to the parts of the query too. The best way to know about them is, search `posts_clauses` in "wp-includes/query.php". Just 3-4 lines before this filter should be a series of filters to filter out the full query part-by-part. The filter tags are self explanatory & you can experiment with them to see which combination works out the best for you

Comment: I see what you mean, probably it needs more checking from my behalf. Thanks.